# Java Cipher AES equivalent to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes

Currently I have to write a web application which should connect to a Java Server. Currently AES is used for encryption and is implemented like this:

```
Key key = generateKeyAES();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
return new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(encVal));
```

I have to do the same in JavaScript now but with several libraries I was not able to reproduce encrypted Java value in JavaScript. Does anybod know a JavaScript library to get the same result as the Java AES encryption?

Comment: Gibberish AES. https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes

Comment: Gibberish returns a different algorithm every time it runs. In Java it is always the same.